# Why does my game start before the mode is chosen?

Tags: python, pong

I'm new to python (first day), so I'm sorry if my coding doesn't make sense.

For my first actual project, I wanted to code "Pong". I want the game to be able to choose between "player vs player" and "player vs cpu" by either pressing "p" or "c" keys, but somehow it automatically runs the "player vs player" mode even before any of the keys are pressed.

Here is the code:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Pong")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width = 800, height = 600)
wn.tracer(0)
mode = "none"
print("Press 'p' for player vs player or 'c' for player vs cpu")

def pvp():
    mode = "pvp"

    # Paddle A
    paddleA = turtle.Turtle()
    paddleA.speed(0)
    paddleA.shape("square")
    paddleA.shapesize(stretch_wid = 5, stretch_len = 1)
    paddleA.color("white")
    paddleA.penup()
    paddleA.goto(-350, 0)

    # Paddle B
    paddleB = turtle.Turtle()
    paddleB.speed(0)
    paddleB.shape("square")
    paddleB.shapesize(stretch_wid = 5, stretch_len = 1)
    paddleB.color("white")
    paddleB.penup()
    paddleB.goto(350, 0)

    # Ball
    ball = turtle.Turtle()
    ball.speed(0)
    ball.shape("circle")
    ball.color("white")
    ball.penup()
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    ball.dx = 0.5
    import random
    angle = random.randint(3, 7)
    ball.dy = angle * 0.1

    # Function
    def paddleA_up():
        y = paddleA.ycor()
        y += 20
        paddleA.sety(y)

    def paddleA_down():
        y = paddleA.ycor()
        y -= 20
        paddleA.sety(y)

    def paddleB_up():
        y = paddleB.ycor()
        y += 20
        paddleB.sety(y)

    def paddleB_down():
        y = paddleB.ycor()
        y -= 20
        paddleB.sety(y)

    # Keyboard binding
    wn.listen()
    wn.onkeypress(paddleA_up, "w")
    wn.onkeypress(paddleA_down, "s")
    wn.onkeypress(paddleB_up, "Up")
    wn.onkeypress(paddleB_down, "Down")

    # Game Loop
    while mode == "pvp":
        wn.update()

        # Ball movement
        ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
        ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

        # Borders
        if ball.ycor() > 290:
            ball.sety(290)
            ball.dy *= -1
        if ball.ycor() < -290:
            ball.sety(-290)
            ball.dy *= -1
        if ball.xcor() > 390:
            ball.setx(390)
            ball.dx = 0
            ball.dy = 0
        if ball.xcor() < -390:
            ball.setx(-390)
            ball.dx *= 0
            ball.dy = 0

        # Ball collide into paddle
        if ball.xcor() > 330 and (ball.ycor() < paddleB.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddleB.ycor() - 50):
            ball.setx(330)
            ball.dx *= -1
            if ball.dy > 0:
                i = 1
            else:
                if ball.dy < 0:
                    i = -1
            ball.dy = random.randint(3, 7) * 0.1 * i
        if ball.xcor() < -330 and (ball.ycor() < paddleA.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddleA.ycor() - 50):
            ball.setx(-330)
            ball.dx *= -1
            if ball.dy > 0:
                i = 1
            else:
                if ball.dy < 0:
                    i = -1
            ball.dy = random.randint(3, 7) * 0.1 * i
        if paddleA.ycor() > 250:
            paddleA.sety(250)
        if paddleA.ycor() < -250:
            paddleA.sety(-250)
        if paddleB.ycor() > 250:
            paddleB.sety(250)
        if paddleB.ycor() < -250:
            paddleB.sety(-250)

def cpu():
    mode = "cpu"

    # Paddle A
    paddleA = turtle.Turtle()
    paddleA.speed(0)
    paddleA.shape("square")
    paddleA.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
    paddleA.color("white")
    paddleA.penup()
    paddleA.goto(-350, 0)

    # Paddle B
    paddleB = turtle.Turtle()
    paddleB.speed(0)
    paddleB.shape("square")
    paddleB.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
    paddleB.color("white")
    paddleB.penup()
    paddleB.goto(350, 0)

    # Ball
    ball = turtle.Turtle()
    ball.speed(0)
    ball.shape("circle")
    ball.color("white")
    ball.penup()
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    ball.dx = 0.5
    import random

    angle = random.randint(3, 7)
    ball.dy = angle * 0.1

    # Function
    def paddleA_up():
        y = paddleA.ycor()
        y += 20
        paddleA.sety(y)

    def paddleA_down():
        y = paddleA.ycor()
        y -= 20
        paddleA.sety(y)

    def paddleB_up():
        y = paddleB.ycor()
        y += 20
        paddleB.sety(y)

    def paddleB_down():
        y = paddleB.ycor()
        y -= 20
        paddleB.sety(y)

    # Keyboard binding
    wn.listen()
    wn.onkeypress(paddleA_up, "w")
    wn.onkeypress(paddleA_down, "s")

    # Game Loop
    while mode == "cpu":
        wn.update()

        # Ball movement
        ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
        ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

        # Borders
        if ball.ycor() > 290:
            ball.sety(290)
            ball.dy *= -1
        if ball.ycor() < -290:
            ball.sety(-290)
            ball.dy *= -1
        if ball.xcor() > 390:
            ball.setx(390)
            ball.dx = 0
            ball.dy = 0
        if ball.xcor() < -390:
            ball.setx(-390)
            ball.dx *= 0
            ball.dy = 0

        # Ball collide into paddle
        if ball.xcor() > 330 and (ball.ycor() < paddleB.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddleB.ycor() - 50):
            ball.setx(330)
            ball.dx *= -1
            if ball.dy > 0:
                i = 1
            else:
                if ball.dy < 0:
                    i = -1
            ball.dy = random.randint(3, 7) * 0.1 * i
        if ball.xcor() < -330 and (ball.ycor() < paddleA.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddleA.ycor() - 50):
            ball.setx(-330)
            ball.dx *= -1
            if ball.dy > 0:
                i = 1
            else:
                if ball.dy < 0:
                    i = -1
            ball.dy = random.randint(3, 7) * 0.1 * i
        if paddleA.ycor() > 250:
            paddleA.sety(250)
        if paddleA.ycor() < -250:
            paddleA.sety(-250)
        paddleB.ycor(ball.ycor())

while mode == "none":
    wn.listen()
    wn.onkeypress(pvp(), "p")
    wn.onkeypress(cpu(), "c")
```

P.S. I added the random in there because I want the angle of the ball to a slight variation each time it hits the paddle.

Comment: The problems are the brackets in `wn.onkeypress(pvp(), "p")`. It should read `wn.onkeypress(pvp, "p")`. You don't want to execute `pvp` immediately but pass the function as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

That is because at the end of your file you have

```
wn.onkeypress(pvp(), "p")
wn.onkeypress(cpu(), "c")
```

instead of

```
wn.onkeypress(pvp, "p")
wn.onkeypress(cpu, "c")
```

Notice the missing brackets `()`?

---

The `wn.onkeypress` method takes a function and a character as arguments. When you type `pvp()` the function is executed immediately and the return value is passed to `wn.onkeypress`.

But you want to pass the function itself, so that it can be executed as soon as there is a key press. Therefore you need to pass only the name of the function without the brackets `()`.

---

You could also solve your problem by using the `input` function.

```
while True:
    response = input("Press 'p' for player vs player or 'c' for player vs cpu: ")
    if len(response) > 0 and response == "p":
        pvp()
        break
    if len(response) > 0 and response == "c":
        cpu()
        break
    if len(response) > 0 and response == "x": # if player wants to exit program
        break
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... but the program stops responding after I run it.... what does that mean?

Comment: @Khaojao06301 I added another solution using `input`. I am however not very experienced with Turtle so i wasn't able to find a solution. Sorry.